# Make error bar to a converted value

Tags: plot, error-handling, statistics, gnuplot, gnu

Im trying to make errorbars to a already converted value. I have value in the dat file as uk gallons per minute and have now converted it into m^3/min.

My problem is that i cannot get my error bars when i also convert the value. Initially i just bracket the converting and then the accuracy on 0.0025(0.25%) but no error bars appear..

```
set yrange [34:37.5]
set xlabel "Time [min]"
set ylabel "Flow [m^3/min]"
plot '2015 08 30 0000 Pelletizer Feed (Wide).dat'  every ::2372::2459 using 4:($17*0.161) w l lc rgb 'green' title "Run 1", \
                        ''  every ::2372::2459 using 4:17:(($17*0.161)*0.0025) w errorbar lc rgb 'green' notitle, \
    '2015 08 30 0000 Pelletizer Feed (Wide).dat'  every ::2498::2565 using 4:($17*0.161) w l lc rgb 'blue' title "Run 2", \
                                ''  every ::2498::2565 using 4:17:(($17*0.161)*0.0025) w errorbar lc rgb 'blue' notitle, \
                        35.42 title "SP" with lines linestyle 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When plotting with lines and with errorbars you are using different y-values. You have `using 4:($17*0.161)` for the lines, but `using 4:17:(($17*0.161)*0.0025)` for the errorbars, so that the errorbars are out of your yrange. Try:

```
set yrange [34:37.5]
set xlabel "Time (min)"
set ylabel "Flow (m^3/min)"
file = '2015 08 30 0000 Pelletizer Feed (Wide).dat'
set linetype 1 lc rgb 'green'
plot file every ::2372::2459 using 4:($17*0.161) w l lt 1 title "Run 1", \
  '' every ::2372::2459 using 4:($17*0.161):(($17*0.161)*0.0025) w errorbar lt 1 notitle
```